# Ajax request works on local server but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have built my first website and it works on local server but not online. The problem is loading a json file with Ajax. In the published version I get the error message that my object is undefined.

This is a (simplified) version of my code that shows the problem:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "json/torp.json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        torp = data;

        console.log('great success!');
        console.log(torp.items[3]);
    },
    error: function (/* request, error */) {
        console.log('Network error has occurred please try again!');
    }
```

This is the message in the console when running on local server:

```
great success!  main.js:37:13
Object { id: "brunskar", title: "<h2>Brunskär</h2>", image: "img/countryside.jpg" }
```

But when I publish online this is what I get:

```
great success!  main.js:37:13
TypeError: torp.items is undefined
```

In the Utilities Net section I get status code 200 and the whole content of the JSON file is readable under the "reply" tab, so it seems like the file is loaded. But I don't understand why my object is undefined.

Comment: Update your question with server side code too.

Comment: Note the `contentType` option tells jQuery what type of data is being sent out, not what type of data is coming in. Since you are not sending data at all here, it is not needed. You probably meant to use dataType, eg `dataType:'json'`. Do a console log of `torp` to see if it is what you think it is. It might be that jQuery is not auto parsing the json, and `torp` might be just the actual JSON text

Comment: Sorry, there is no server side code, I'm only using client side code in my website.

Comment: Then try with `console.log(JSON.parse(torp));` and see (also paste here) which data comes from server.

Comment: When I do `console.log(JSON.parse(torp));` I get this output in console: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`
I get the same output on my local server as I do online.

Comment: Problem solved by changing `contentType: "application/json"`to `dataType: "json"`!
Thank you for the help!

Comment: That's why I told you to parse your response in `JSON`. If proper `JSON` string comes from server then you can get `JSON` object by using `JSON.parse()` method. Anyways, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an asynchronous issue (your page is loading before your ajax call can return the data, therefor it is returned as undefined) one way to solve this is to put a function inside your ajax call that fires your page functions that use the data being returned by the call.

```
$.ajax({
url: "json/torp.json",
contentType: "application/json",
success: function (data) {
    torp = data;

    console.log('great success!');
    console.log(torp.items[3]);
    function usePageData (); <----calls webpage function utilizing 
    data 
},
error: function (/* request, error */) {
    console.log('Network error has occurred please try again!');
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

to

```
dataType: "json"!
```

I used the tip from Patrick Evans in one of the comments. Thank you for the help!